# Skew-hermitian also a contraction?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, hermitian-matrices, contraction-operator

If a matrix is skew-hermitian, is it also a contraction?

I've been playing around with skew-hermitian operators on Hilbert spaces, and found this to be true on a couple of examples. So I was wondering if there is anything we can say about the relationship :)

Comment: A skew Hermitian matrix $A$ satisfies $A^*=-A$, which means that $iA$ is Hermitian. For example, $3iI$ is skew Hermitian, but is not a contraction.